# Запуск операции(функции, метода) из основного потока

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, многопоточность, ui

Выполняю считывание данных через WebSocket, данные попадают в инфраструктуру проекта и обрабатываются, потом добавляются в коллекцию. Во время работы, используется многопоточность, но как так необходимо отображать данные коллекции на форме я вывожу их через DataGridView.DataSource = List<...>. Данные при обработке не добавляются когда открыта форма, значит коллекция блокируется на добавление и ожидает повторной привязки. Подскажите как вызвать определенный метод, например Add - добавлении данных в коллекцию в UI потоке?

Comment: `myWindow.Invoke(new Action(() =>{ /*......*/ }));` ?

Comment: Используйте `BindingList` или `ObservableCollection` вместо простого `List`. У элементов внутри коллекции должен быть реализован интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Гм, я потратил некоторое время на анализ проблемы. Оказывается, `ListBox` обновляется динамически из другого потока (с привязкой к `BindingList` и использованием `Invoke`). А вот с `DataGridView` дело обстоит плохо. Вероятно, дело в его внутреннем устройстве.

Comment: @tym32167 метод находится глубоко в проекте и нет возможности вот так вызвать, ваш прошлый совет с проксированием формой тоже не особо подходит

Comment: @Alexander Petrov с ListBox такая же ситуация, пока не перезагружу форму с элементом, данные не добавятся... как будто блокируется доступ до коллекции но при этом она обновляется НО данные не добавляются когда она используется. Вот мне и кажется что нужен перенос в UI

Comment: Нужен [мсвп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - пример кода (без сокетов и прочего, не важного для сути выполнения), создающий и заполняющий коллекцию с привязкой к гриду. Чтобы его можно было скопировать и выполнить.